# Putting the column type from the DB to a XML attribute

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

Doing the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM MY_DATA
FOR XML PATH('NODE'), TYPE, ROOT('ROOT')
```

I have the following output:

```
<ROOT>
    <NODE>
        <THE_ID>11</Facility_ID>
        <Station_ID>HA</Station_ID>
        <Case_No>731</Case_No>
    </NODE>
</ROOT>
```

What I'm wondering is whether is possible to have an output like the following:

```
<ROOT>
    <NODE>
        <THE_ID int>11</Facility_ID>
        <Station_ID varchar="30">HA</Station_ID>
        <Case_No varchar="50>731</Case_No>
    </NODE>
</ROOT>
```

With the types as attributes.
Is it possible?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just create alias with adding data type.

Comment: Your example is riddled with things that don't look right. `THE_ID` in your output is "00011" which is a string (sql would not output the leading 0's if it's an `int`). Second, the attribute in your example output is the name of the data type, with the value being... it's length? Should we assume you want an attribute called, say, `datatype` whose value is the data type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the information you're after.  Tie it into your query and play with.

To get an item as an attribute, use "as [@AttributeName]".

For instance in your example change the Select Station_Id portion to Select a, b, Station_Id as [@Station_Id].

'

```
DECLARE @Table VARCHAR(MAX) = 'YourTableName'

SELECT t.name AS [Table]
    ,   c.name AS [Column]
    ,   TYPE_NAME(c.user_type_id) AS [Type]
    ,   c.max_length AS [Size]
    ,   CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN ''
             ELSE 'No Nulls'
        END AS Nullable
    ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY t.name ORDER BY c.name ASC ) AS rnk

    FROM sys.columns AS c
        JOIN sys.tables AS t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    WHERE t.name LIKE @Table
  --      AND c.name IN ( 'thiscol', 'thatcol' )
    ORDER BY t.name
    ,   c.name
```